# Linux kernel read custom function

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module

Trying to make a read function, that not only adds the numbers together. But also counts how many numbers were added.

Needs to be used in such script:

```
for i in 1 2 4 8 16 32 64; do
   echo $i > /dev/summer0
   sleep 60
done
```

But also just using a test case.

Here is the kernel module code:

```
/* the memory of the device
*/
int total;

/* Global variables declared as staic, so are global within the file.*/
static char *msg_Ptr;
static char msg[BUF_LEN];
static int n;

/* called after the device is opened
*/
int device_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    printk("\nsummer device is open\n");
    total = 0;

    printk(msg);
    msg_Ptr = msg;

    return 0;
}

/* Read function */
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{    
    /* Number of bytes actually written to the buffer */
    int bytes_read = 0;

    /* If we're at the end of the message, return 0 signifying end of file */
    if (*msg_Ptr == 0) return 0;

    /* Actually put the data into the buffer */
    while (length && *msg_Ptr) 
    {
        /* The buffer is in the user data segment, not the kernel segment;
        *  assignment won't work. We have to use put_use which copies data from 
        *  the kernel data segment to the user data segment. */
        __put_user(*(msg_Ptr++), buffer++);

        length++;
        n++;
    }
    /* Most read functions return the number of bytes put into the buffer */
    return n;
}

/* handling of ioctl events
*/
long device_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int ioctl_num, unsigned long ioctl_param)
{
    int number;
    switch(ioctl_num)
    {
        case SUMMER_SET:
            __get_user(number, (int*)ioctl_param);
            total += number;
            break;
        case SUMMER_GET:
            __put_user(total, (int*)ioctl_param);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* table of event handlers of the device
*/
struct file_operations fops =
{
    read   : device_read,
    //write  : device_write,
    open   : device_open,
    release: device_close,
    unlocked_ioctl : device_ioctl
};
```

As for the testcase

```
int n;    
int main(void)
{
    int sum;
    char buffer[BUF_LEN];

    /* open character device   */
    int fd = open("/dev/summer0", O_RDWR);  // open device
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        printf("no device found\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int nc = read(fd,buffer,4,n);

    for(;;)
    {
        int num;
        printf("Number (exit with 0) = ");
        while(scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
            ;
        printf("-- %d --\n", num);
        if(num <= 0) break;

        /* use ioctl to pass a value to the character device     */
        ioctl(fd, SUMMER_SET, &num);
        n++;
    }

    /* use ioctl to get a value from the character device   */
    ioctl(fd, SUMMER_GET, &sum);

    printf("#char = %d\n", nc);
    printf("Result = %d\n", sum);
    printf("Buffer: %s\n" , buffer);
    close(fd);                         // close device
    return 0;
}
```

The program is keeping track of the amount of numbers entered during a single test, but it is supposed to keep track of the numbers until I install the kernel module.

Comment: What you try to do is not clear... Can you describe what you do (ie: 1- modprobe, 2- shell code, 3- c program...) what you get as result and what you wanted to do? In short a [mcve]

Comment: You define `msg` and `msg_Ptr` but you never write anything into the associated memory

Comment: you have `total=0` in `device_open`, so you reset the value each time when opening the device

Comment: The global idea of the program is that it doesn't only sums the numbers entered, and also gives me a count of the amount of numbers entered in total.

Comment: You need to clarify -- possibly to yourself; certainly to SO -- how you want this to behave.  The C code resets `total` every time the device is opened, and communicates through `ioctl` codes.  The script example communicates through writing to the device (which doesn't appear to have a handler) and appears to assume the total / count is accumulated over several such writes.